# Visual Studio - Load References Outside Compile Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, subdirectory

I'm using Visual Studio to make a C# program. I have a 3rd party Dll that I'm loading. It works, but I want it to be in a subdirectory of the compile directory. (Release\lib\ instead of Release). I can do this using the exe.config file, but I don't want users to be able to change where the program looks for the Dll. So, how do I reference Dlls in a subdirectory without using the exe.config?

Comment: Copy it to the folder.. remove the current reference and then go to Reference -> add and navigate to where the .dll located now.. here is a question.. when you deploy the application.. are you going to make a folder on the target machine based on where you are putting it on the local.. or are you going to set copy local = true..? have you thought about using the GAC if you are porting to a target machine..????

Comment: I already tried that... It either copies it to the output directory, or, if i turn that off, gives an error at runtime. On the target machine, it will have the bin folder with the exe, and then a lib folder inside that with dlls. Also some other stuff, but that's not important right now. Also, I've seen other posts where people said you could use the GAC but it was a very bad idea... So if it's possible to do it without that, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need [AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath.aspx) property setup for your domain. 
Specify in this property the folder paths (if more then one delimited with ";") where your reference assemblies are. In this way you make a sign to assembly to lookup into specified directories for references it needs.

Pay attention, that this property works only for directories, that are sub-directories o bin path, but it seems exactly your case.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "path1;path2;...";
```

Good luck.

Comment: Okay, this seems like it's what I need, but where do I put it? Sorry, I'm not good with this kind of stuff. In my Program.cs at the top of the Main() function I have put AppDomainSetup appdomainsetup = new AppDomainSetup();
   appdomainsetup.PrivateBinPath = "\\lib\\"; but how do i use that variable?

Comment: That doesn't work :/. I tried printing out the value changed right after it was changed, and nothing came out. So, that means it's not updating that variable. I think what you have to do is create a new domain and set that. I'm trying to figure out how to do that now....

Comment: @Aidan: what variable are you talking about?

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath. I set it to "\\lib\\" (two \\ as an escape), but it didn't help (it still didn't find the dll in the lib folder). So right below the place i set PrivateBinPath to "\\lib\\", I consoled out PrivateBinPath. It was blank - so that means it's not getting set correctly. I've tried a few other things to set it, but nothing works.

Comment: @Aidan: put not *relative*, but **absolute** path into that property

Comment: That didn't work either. When I tried to console it out, it still printed out nothing. :/ Thanks for your help so far! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to specify PrivateBinPath, before starting to load dlls.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "path";
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

And if a dll in application folder needs another dll in PrivateBinPath folder we specified, it will not work. All dlls must be in the same folder...